# VMSS auto register with Custom DNS

Tags: azure, internal-dns, dns-server

We’re creating a VMSS and we use a custom DNS with extending AD from on-premises, but we are not sure how to register the VMs as the scale set scales out, in azure DNS we can create a private zone and use auto registration but not with our custom DNS.
Basically I’m trying to understand as each VMs scales out how do the newly created VMs register with dns?
Thanks

Comment: This is going to be down to what you DNS provider offers.

Comment: I was hoping to use AD DNS, but what I’m thinking is as the VMs are created in the availability set they wouldn’t need to be registered in DNS, wouldn’t traffic just route to them as they form part of the backend pool for the load balancer on the VMSS?

Comment: If your VM's are behind a load balancer (it is possible to turn that off), and you want to load balance the traffic, then you are correct, the only thing you need is the loadbalancer name

Comment: @SamCogan thanks, a quick related  follow up question if we extend AD DS into Azure, can we still have Azure DNS running and use a conditional forwarder to send traffic to Azure DNS?

Comment: Sorry Azure Private DNS not Azure DNS I meant.